# how can we have images at google search text result

Tags: seo

Can someone help me on how to setup such a result:

[image]

Want to know the mechanism on how can we set the parameters that it shows also the image on the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your CMS system Authorship tags to get the writers image in your search results.

More info you will find on [Google Authorship home page](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/authorship/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Google Authorship](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/authorship-markup-and-web-search.html).